# Eclipse project to double-clickable file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable

This might be an odd question, but it's one that I would love solved.

In Eclipse, I've made a project. Beautiful GUI and all. When I hit `Run as Java Application` (or just `Run` for that matter), it all works wondrously.

What I want to know is:

What is the easiest way to make my precious project into a double-clickable file? So that when I mail it to a friend, said friend can just double-click the file and see what I do when I hit `Run` in Eclipse?

I'm a little new to Eclipse still, so the least complicated answer which works is the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options. You can make:

- runnable jar, from eclipse export and select a runnable jar as shown below:

  - **Step 1**

  [image: Step 1]

  - **Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

- exe file or other runnable using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) - a free cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables)

Example:
**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**
[image]

Comment: You can export the project classes and resources as jar, right-click on the "project => Export => Java => Jar file"